# Why is header including sufficient for definitions?

Tags: c++, header, compiler-construction, declaration, definition

as far as i understood; headerfiles declare things. Now including header files like #include iostream includes the header file iostream.h. This is telling the compiler for example „there is something called: cout“.
QUESTION: How does the compiler get to the definition of cout (or all the other functions)? In my understanding the compiler only gets to know names and types but no definitions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Definitions of most of the stuff from standard library that are not inlined come from linking standard library, which usually happens implicitly.

Comment: The definition of `cout` has been compiled earlier, and stored in a library file, where the linker will find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually: It doesn't. It needs to know *how* the objects look like, what interfaces they offer (so for `std::cout` that's a some `std::ostream` stream object, apparently a subclass of) and that such objects *do* exist *somewhere*. That's it. What the compiler then does is adding placeholders for that object – right as it does for function calls as well.

After compilation there's then a second unit: the linker. As its name tells, it links all those compilation units together. If it now sees such a place holder it will replace it with the address of the object or function – which must exist, of course (for `std::cout`, there's an `extern` declaration in the header, but *some* other source file *must* have implemented it without `extern` – and if pre-compiled in some library), otherwise a linker error is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. If i get you right: the linker needs to know where to look for the definitions which are precompiled in a .lib file. But the question remains now: how does the linker know where to look for this lib file? In standard libraries i could imagine that this is some default location but what if i want to include my own library with its header and lib files?

Comment: @Wendel You need to tell the linker which libraries to use – apart from the standard C++ libraries, which are included by default. These libraries are more or less just a collection of already compiled units, i.e. object files, and these have a special format from which the linker reads which objects and functions they actually contain at which (relative) location.